# Why when using .apply on pandas dataframe is it giving incorrect result? My loop version works

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames:

1. `df_topics_temp contains` a matrix with column `id`
2. `df_mapping contains` a mapping of `id` to a `parentID`

I'm trying to populate the column `parent.id` in `df_topics_temp` with the `parentID` in `df_mapping`.

I have written a solution using loops although it is very cumbersome. It works. My solution using pandas `.apply` to the `df_topics_temp` doesn't work

Solution 1 (works):

```
def isnan(value):
  try:
      import math
      return math.isnan(float(value))
  except:
      return False

for x in range(0, df_topics_temp['id'].count()):
    topic_id_loop = df_topics_temp['topic.id'].iloc[x]
    mapping_row = df_mapping[df_mapping['id'] == topic_id_loop]
    parent_id = mapping_row['parentId'].iloc[0]
    
    if isnan(parent_id):
        df_topics_temp['parent.id'].iloc[x] = mapping_row['id'].iloc[0]
    else:     
        df_topics_temp['parent.id'].iloc[x] = topic_id_loop
```

Solution 2 (does not work):

```
def map_function(x):
        df_topics_temp = df_mapping.loc[df_mapping['id'] == x]
        temp = df_topics_temp['parentId'].iloc[0]
        return temp

df_topics_temp['parent.id'] = df_topics_temp['topic.id'].apply(map_function)

df_topics_temp.head()
```

The second solution (pandas `.apply`) is not populating the `parent.id` column in `df_topics_temp`.

Thank you for the help

## Update 1

```
<ipython-input-68-a2e8d9a21c26> in map_function(row)
      1 def map_function(row):
----> 2         row['parent.id'] = df_mapping.loc[df_mapping['id']==row['topic.id']]['parentId'].values[0]
      3         return row

IndexError: ('index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0', 'occurred at index 190999')
```

Comment: First of all - I think you don't have to redefine isnan, the numpy version should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, 'apply' takes a row and returns a row.
So, you want your function to return a row. Yours returns a value.
For example:

```
#setting up the dataframes
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'name':['alice','bob'],'id':[1,2]})
mapping = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'id':[1,2,3,4],'parent_id':[100,200,100,200]})

#mapping function
def f(row):
    if any(mapping['id']==row['id']):
        row['parent_id'] = mapping.loc[mapping['id']==row['id']]['parent_id'].values[0]
    else: # missing value
        row['parent_id'] = np.nan
    return row

df1.apply(f,axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Itamar. That makes sense. I will try it out

Comment: Please see Update 1 in my original post above. It is the error that I'm getting when I apply the code you suggested to my dataframe. Please help

Comment: First of all, please check that the offending row (190999) has a legitimate 'parent' by ID, and it's not a problem in the data.

Comment: Anyway, I've added a condition to handle missing values. It should handle your missing values and not result in an exception.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped and the problem is solver, I think you should "accept" the answer.

Comment: I've done that now. Sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow. I now know what to do and not to say "thank you" in the comments. I do however appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm new here too. Happy programming!